# convert percentage to range [-1;1]

Tags: math, powerbi, powerquery, m

I am working on a project in PowerBI. 
I want to convert a column of decimals (percentages) to a range from -1 to 1.

This is the table I'm using right now:

```
FirstName | Score
Jack      | 0.75
John      | 0.50
Reese     | 0.00
Mike      | 1.00
```

And the desired result is:

```
FirstName | Score
Jack      | 0.50
John      | 0.00
Reese     | -1.00
Mike      | 1.00
```

I am strugling with the math behind this. If I got that part, I could make it by using m-language in PowerBI.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those scores don't actually look like percentages, they're more like fractions - for example, the percentage for `0.75` would be `75`.

So, if you're talking about mapping `0..1` to `-1..1`, it's a simple matter to apply the transformation:

```
newVal = oldVal * 2 - 1
```

The multiplication by two first scales it into the range `0..2` while the subtraction then shifts it into the range `-1..1`.

Answer (score -5):

I think it's very entitled of you to present no work at all and ask for a free solution. Any basic statistics text will describe how to rebase and scale a set of data. However, this will do what you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util qw/ min max /;

my @data = <DATA>;
my ($min, $max, $delta);

{
    my @n = map /([\d.]+)\s*\z/, @data;

    ( $min, $max ) = ( min(@n), max(@n) );
    $delta = $max - $min;
}

for ( @data ) {
    s{ ( [\d.]+ ) (?= \s*\z ) }{ sprintf '%.2f', ( $1 - $min ) * 2 / $delta - 1 }xe;
    print;
}

__DATA__
FirstName | Score
Jack      | 0.75
John      | 0.50
Reese     | 0.00
Mike      | 1.00
```

#### output

```
FirstName | Score
Jack      | 0.50
John      | 0.00
Reese     | -1.00
Mike      | 1.00
```